# Custom error using simple-schema in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, simple-schema

```
SimpleSchema.messages({
"minString": `[label] must be at least [min] ${this.min===1 ? 'character' : 'characters'}`    
});
```

But this.min doesn`t work, because this === window. How can I access the value on min, and according to value, set correct word?

Object from schema:

```
 title: {
  type: String,
  min: 1,
  max: 40
},
```

I want to use this custom message with different schemas with different min values, so I need to dynamic setting

Comment: What version of Meteor are you using? I can't seem to find SimpleSchema.messages({}) in the online API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with Meteor but you could write a function to generate the `minString` value before adding it to the property:

```
var obj = {
      title: {
         type: String,
         min: 1,
         max: 40
      }
}

var generateMinString = function(title){
    var characterText = (title.min===1) ? 'character' : 'characters';
    return `[label] must be at least ` +title.min + " " + characterText;
}


SimpleSchema.messages({
   "minString": generateMinString(obj.title)
});
```

Of course you'll need to change how you access the `title` object depending on the setup of your containing object.